# How to Trigger GA Event for Every Single Pageview (of a certain type)

Tags: google-analytics, php, javascript, analytics

Thanks, edited my question.

I need a reliable way to capture a GA event *whenever* the GA tracking code fires for a particular page only. Doing so because we want to assign a dollar value to simply viewing a certain page (or type of page), and this can happen multiple times per visit, so a destination based goal isn't feasible

I tried using a window.onload javascript (also tried window.onbeforeunload) to trigger the event, but I can only get about 80% of the pageviews to become events (and only about 12% for our mobile website!). Not accurate enough yet for "prime time"

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In your GA script you can place the event. Although I can't think of a single reason you would want to do this, that's your thing, not mine I suppose.

Just place your event in the same script tag right above the first line (usually `var _gaq = _gaq || [];`).

Also, PHP has nothing to do with JS as it is [server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting), JS is [client-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting).

Comment: Thanks I'd be glad to give this solution a try and mark your answer as accepted; would you mind putting that code in context for me, i.e. making this line of code look more complete? This looks kind of sparse to my eyes